# SQL Server WHERE clause XPath with multiple nodes and conditions

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have this XML in a table column in SQL Server:

```
<root>
    <Request>
        <RequestData>
            <VendorLeadList>
                <VendorLeadItem>
                    <CampaignOfferTypeID>REN</CampaignOfferTypeID>
                    <LeadDispositionID>Lead</LeadDispositionID>
                    <Jurisdiction>NY</Jurisdiction>
                    <FirstName>Shikasta</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Kashti</LastName>
                    <MessageId>1347_1483825159115_c8273</MessageId>
                </VendorLeadItem>
            </VendorLeadList>
        </RequestData>
        <DualMessageID/>
        <AzureBlobFile/>
        <AzureBlobImageList/>
    </Request>
</root>
```

I want to query all the records where it matches some nodes with specific values. For example I want all records where `LeadDispositionID=Lead` and `Jurisdiction=NY` and `CampaignOfferTypeID=REN` and a `MessageId` element exists (doesn't matter what value.)

I tried this but it doesn't work (no errors but the conditions doesn't match and it returns other records):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
  FROM [Messages]
  WHERE PayLoadXml.exist('//LeadDispositionID[.="Lead"] and //CampaignOfferTypeID[.="REN"] and //Jurisdiction[.="NY"] and //MessageId') = 1
  ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your xpath is definitely fine here. I'd recon there something with `PayLoadXml.exist()` function.

Comment: @Granitosaurus no, you cannot simply combine nodes with `and`...

Comment: @Shnugo What do you mean? `and` is completely valid xpath and you can combine nodes like that, xpath will evaluate every node individually and return either `'1'` if there are matches, otherwise `'0'`.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Just use my sample code and place `WHERE itm.exist(N'LeadDispositionID[.="Lead"] and Jurisdiction[.="NY"]')=1` as final line. Try it with `and Jurisdiction[.="NY"]` and without. Try it even with something like `and Jurisdiction[.="Blah"]` or `and xyz[.="Blah"]`. You won't get the expected result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine nodes within `.exist()` simply with `and`. Your own example would work like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @Messages
WHERE PayLoadXml.exist('//VendorLeadItem[LeadDispositionID[.="Lead"] and CampaignOfferTypeID[.="REN"] and Jurisdiction[.="NY"] and MessageId/text()]') = 1
```

Try it like this:

First a declared table to *mock-up* your Messages table. Insert 3 cases:

```
DECLARE @messages TABLE(SomeDescription VARCHAR(100),PayLoadXml XML);
INSERT INTO @messages VALUES
('Your example'
,'<root>
    <Request>
        <RequestData>
            <VendorLeadList>
                <VendorLeadItem>
                    <CampaignOfferTypeID>REN</CampaignOfferTypeID>
                    <LeadDispositionID>Lead</LeadDispositionID>
                    <Jurisdiction>NY</Jurisdiction>
                    <FirstName>Shikasta</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Kashti</LastName>
                    <MessageId>1347_1483825159115_c8273</MessageId>
                </VendorLeadItem>
            </VendorLeadList>
        </RequestData>
        <DualMessageID/>
        <AzureBlobFile/>
        <AzureBlobImageList/>
    </Request>
</root>'
)
,('LeadDispositionID=Slave'
,'<root>
    <Request>
        <RequestData>
            <VendorLeadList>
                <VendorLeadItem>
                    <CampaignOfferTypeID>REN</CampaignOfferTypeID>
                    <LeadDispositionID>Slave</LeadDispositionID>
                    <Jurisdiction>NY</Jurisdiction>
                    <FirstName>Bruno</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Kashti</LastName>
                    <MessageId>1347_1483825159115_c8273</MessageId>
                </VendorLeadItem>
            </VendorLeadList>
        </RequestData>
        <DualMessageID/>
        <AzureBlobFile/>
        <AzureBlobImageList/>
    </Request>
</root>'
)
,('LeadDispositionID=Lead but No MessageId'
,'<root>
    <Request>
        <RequestData>
            <VendorLeadList>
                <VendorLeadItem>
                    <CampaignOfferTypeID>REN</CampaignOfferTypeID>
                    <LeadDispositionID>Lead</LeadDispositionID>
                    <Jurisdiction>NY</Jurisdiction>
                    <FirstName>Bruno</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Kashti</LastName>
                    <MessageId></MessageId>
                </VendorLeadItem>
            </VendorLeadList>
        </RequestData>
        <DualMessageID/>
        <AzureBlobFile/>
        <AzureBlobImageList/>
    </Request>
</root>'
);
```

This is the query:
The `CROSS APPLY` will ensure, that only nodes with a MessageId are taken into account. The `WHERE` will apply an additional filter

```
SELECT m.*
FROM @messages AS m
CROSS APPLY m.PayLoadXml.nodes(N'/root/Request/RequestData/VendorLeadList/VendorLeadItem[not(empty(MessageId/text()))]') AS A(itm)
WHERE itm.exist(N'LeadDispositionID[text()="Lead"]')=1
```

If you need to check more than one condition you might use this:

```
WHERE itm.exist(N'.[LeadDispositionID="Slave" and FirstName="Bruno"]')=1
```